# how to receive fast result from access query?

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

i have table (MyTbl) that has 3 field's A,B,C

this table contain 800000 records.

what is the best way to receive fast result ?

i try this:

```
select top 1 A from MyTbl where A='123'
```

but it isn't fast

i work with Access 2007 - and C# program

Comment: Assuming you have an index on the field, don't you also need an ORDER BY for the result to be meaningful?

Answer (score 0):

[Create an index](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-and-use-an-index-to-improve-performance-HA010210347.aspx) on the column `A` in `MyTbl`.

Answer (score 0):

Create an [index](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177495%28office.12%29.aspx) on table `MyTbl`, field `A`.

Comment: thank's for the help, can i get any sample for how to do it ? (the most simple)

Comment: Have you even read the article I have linked to? It is a programmatic version on how to add an index. You can of course do it click-style: `Design -> Field -> Properties -> General -> Indexed`.